# Como llenar datos a través de $POST a una tabla, con arreglos bidimensionales dependientes de varios Select e inputs tipo Checkbox

Tags: php, post, array

Tengo el siguiente formulario con dos Select, cada uno con su respectivo input del tipo Checkbox, para enviarse con $_POST.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>ARREGLOS_</title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="pruebados.php">
    <select name="form[txtmateria][]">
        <option selected value="">SELECCIONE MATERIAS UNO</option>
        <option value="ADMINISTRACION">ADMINISTRACION</option>
        <option value="COMERCIO">COMERCIO</option>
        <option value="SISTEMAS">SISTEMAS</option>
    </select>   
    <label><input name="form[txtmateria][][txtgrado][]" value="SALA_1" type="checkbox">SALA_1</label>
    <label><input name="form[txtmateria][][txtgrado][]" value="SALA_2" type="checkbox">SALA_2</label>
    <label><input name="form[txtmateria][][txtgrado][]" value="SALA_3" type="checkbox">SALA_3</label><br>
    <select name="form[txtmateria][]">
        <option selected value="">SELECCIONE MATERIAS DOS</option>
        <option value="TURISMO">TURISMO</option>
        <option value="FOTOGRAFIA">FOTOGRAFIA</option>
        <option value="MUSICA">MUSICA</option>
    </select>
    <label><input name="form[txtmateria][][txtgrado][]" value="SALA_1" type="checkbox">SALA_1</label>
    <label><input name="form[txtmateria][][txtgrado][]" value="SALA_2" type="checkbox">SALA_2</label>
    <label><input name="form[txtmateria][][txtgrado][]" value="SALA_3" type="checkbox">SALA_3</label><br>
<input type="submit" name="btnenviar" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

El código del archivo que recibe el $POST, pruebados.php; esta de la siguiente manera:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['form'] ) ){
echo '<table border="1">';    
echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>MATERIA</th>';
        echo '<th>SALON</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';    
echo '<tbody>';
$txtmateria=$_POST['form'];
foreach ( $txtmateria as $m ) {
  foreach ($m as $p){ 
    for($x=0;$x<count($p);$x++){
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' .$m[$x].'</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$p[$x].'</td>';               
        echo '</tr>'; 
    } 
  }
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>'; }
```

Tomando un ejemplo en el cual selecciono del primer Select  “comercio” y de los Checkbox respectivos solo “Sala_2”, ya para el segundo Select selecciono “fotografía” y del respectivo Checkbox “Sala_1” y “Sala_3”, Un print_r($_POST) me da lo siguiente:

```
Array ( [form] => Array ( [txtmateria] => Array ( 
[0] => COMERCIO 
[1] => Array ( [txtgrado] => Array ( 
    [0] => SALA_2 ) ) 
[2] => FOTOGRAFIA 
[3] => Array ( [txtgrado] => Array ( 
    [0] => SALA_1 ) ) 
[4] => Array ( [txtgrado] => Array ( 
    [0] => SALA_3 ) ) ) )
```

La idea es que la tabla debería mostrarse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo errores de este tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la forma en como estas haciendo el recorrido de las variables, en base al array que pones, esta seria la solución:

```
<?php

$datos = Array ( 'form' => Array ( 'txtmateria' => Array ( 
'COMERCIO ',
 Array ( 'txtgrado' => Array ( 
   'SALA_2' ) ), 
 'FOTOGRAFIA', 
 Array ( 'txtgrado' => Array ( 
 'SALA_1' ) ), 
 Array ( 'txtgrado' => Array ( 
'SALA_3' ) ) ) ));


echo '<table border="1">';    
echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>MATERIA</th>';
        echo '<th>SALON</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';    
echo '<tbody>';
foreach ( $datos as $m  => $v0 ) {
  $mat = '';
  foreach ($v0['txtmateria']  as $p => $v1){ 

      if(!is_array($v1)){
           $mat = $v1;
      }else{

          foreach ($v1['txtgrado']  as $p2 => $v2){ 
              echo '<tr>';
              echo '<td>'.$mat.'</td>';
              echo '<td>'.$v2.'</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
          }

      }

  }
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Si el problema persiste me comentas, si tu problema es resulto no te olvides calificar la respuesta como la que soluciono el problema y que fue útil.

Comment: Tu sugerencia estuvo exelente, el problema era el rrecorrido de los arreglos, en base a tu respuesta modifique los name de los select y los checkbox y logre solucionar el problema, para pasarlos a pruebados.php los llamo a traves de $datos=$_POST['datos']; y todo se soluciona.

Comment: Me alegra q te haya funcionado.